# Iterate over nested yaml dictionary from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator, yaml

I have safe loaded python object by parsing the yaml document similar to below format,

> envdata = yaml.safe_load(data)

```
id: XXX
name: XXX
tecVersion: 1

wrapper: #category
    wrapper-box-1: #instance
        host: XXX
        port: 4567
        tags:
          - ABC
          - VTR


powerWrapper: #category
     pw-box-45: #instance
         host: YYY
         port: 7890
         tags:
           - ABC
```

Each category is a top level array object and instance is an array object inside the category.

Requirement is, given the tag ex: ABC, I want to get all the matching instances in every category as a list. How can I iterate over each and every element and compare the tags and add all matching instances to a array of instances in an optimal way ?

Comment: That is invalid YAML, you start with mapping at the root level, then switch to sequence elements. Correct your YAML input and provide us with more of your (failing) program than loading the YAML.

Comment: @Anthon It is valid now. Actually I have mentioned my requirement and I need the solution algorithm for that. I also have updated the question.

Comment: Because you did not include your failing program, nor the expected output in a non-ambigious way, this is still extremely vague. You want the matching instances of ABC as a list: So you want `["ABC", "ABC"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1.) Each category is a top level array object and instance is an array object inside the category.
>
> (2.) How can I ... compare the tags and add all matching instances to a array of instances ... ?

The definition in (1.) is not exactly terrific, but it's enough to work with.
I disagree with your use of the word "array" or `list`, when apparently a "map" or `dict` is what the category contains.
It would be a bit nicer, I feel, if each instance was guaranteed to contain a key named `'instance'` or `'id'` or something, to distinguish them from sibling entries such as `'tecVersion'`.
Alternatively, all instances might be pushed one level down under a key with a creative name, such as, let's see, maybe we'd call it `'instances'`?

You made it clear that `'wrapper'` is a "category".
I don't know what `'wrapper-box-1'` might be called.
It's too bad you didn't also include a `'wrapper-box-2'` in your example data.

Here is what `yaml` returns:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(envdata)
{'id': 'XXX',
 'name': 'XXX',
 'powerWrapper': {'pw-box-45': {'host': 'YYY', 'port': 7890, 'tags': ['ABC']}},
 'tecVersion': 1,
 'wrapper': {'wrapper-box-1': {'host': 'XXX',
                               'port': 4567,
                               'tags': ['ABC', 'VTR']}}}
```

Ok, let's iterate:

```
def get_tags(putative_category):
    """Generator, returns tags if the input appears to be a category."""
    try:
        for undefined_box_concept, attributes in putative_category.items():
            tags = attributes['tags']
            yield tags
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
        pass

for category_name, category in envdata.items():
    for tags in get_tags(category):
        print(tags, category_name, category)
```

Output:

```
['ABC', 'VTR'] wrapper {'wrapper-box-1': {'host': 'XXX', 'port': 4567, 'tags': ['ABC', 'VTR']}}
['ABC'] powerWrapper {'pw-box-45': {'host': 'YYY', 'port': 7890, 'tags': ['ABC']}}
```

Your problem statement is a little on the vague side.
Once you have the tags in hand, it's not clear to me what you'd want to do with them.
For (2.), a list comprehension with nested `for` loops should suffice, using the generator I supplied.